# Using .Net NewRelic with Multi Threading

Tags: .net, multithreading, newrelic

I have a multi-threaded application that I need to monitor using the .Net NewRelic Agent. The issue that happens is that NewRelic manages to monitor everything until the thread is forked and after that, I cannot get the agent to monitor any method. I need a way to monitor the methods within the children threads, if possible without altering my code.

Comment: As i have realized, it is currently not supported. The only way to do it is to write code. What I did was that I implemented a [BlockingCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) to which the exception logger writes the exceptions and a reader reads and pushes data to the NewRelic monitor. The bottleneck however is the fact that the [NewRelic API](https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api) takes a lock on the monitor while writing and unless you run this entire process in a separate thread, you are going to face some serious issues.